# List of booleans and switching it values upon interaction

Tags: python, list, boolean

Here is the thing! I got a list with 3 boolean variables and I want to switch between them with the press of a button. Each boolean variable represents a function executed by **if** statement. How do I change the previous value and the current value in a smooth way? A better way like using a dictionary instead of a list.

What I tried:

```
Gesture, Mouse, Keyboard = False, False, False 

ActionList  = [Gesture, Mouse, Keyboard]

if ActionList[0]:
   # blah
elif ActionList[1]:
   # blah
elif ActionList[2]:
   # blah
```

Edit:

I managed to put a working code together with the responses I have received until now. Still I think there should be a better way of achieving this.

```
 actions = {"gesture": False, "mouse": False, "keyboard": False}

 CurrentLen = len(actions) # 3

 CurrentAct = 1

 TrueValue = 0

 while True:

     ActionName = actions.keys()[TrueValue]

     ActionValue = actions.values()[TrueValue]

     if actions.values()[(TrueValue - 1 )]: # Disable last
        Disable = actions.keys()[(TrueValue - 1 )]
        print "Disable %s" % (Disable)
        actions[Disable] = not actions[Disable]

     if CurrentAct == CurrentLen:
        CurrentAct = 1
        TrueValue = 0  

     elif CurrentAct < CurrentLen:
        CurrentAct = CurrentAct + 1
        TrueValue = CurrentAct - 1

     if not ActionValue: # Enable current
        print "Enable %s" % (ActionName)
        actions[ActionName] = not actions[ActionName]
```

Comment: What do you mean by "previous value" and "current value"?

Comment: What I meant was the position of the values in the dictionary. Since I'll need to unload the previous function to load the next one in the dictionary. Thanks for your concern so please check my edit for a better understanding.

Comment: Unfortunately, dictionaries don't have an order. You might need to use an OrderedDict.

Comment: I'll do some search on that term and again thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure what you mean, but this might help:

```
actions = {"gesture": False, "mouse": False, "keyboard": False}

if actions["gesture"]:
    ...

if actions["mouse"]:
    ...

if actions["keyboard"]:
    ...
```

This uses a dictionary instead of a list to store the actions.

To change the values you can do this:

```
actions["mouse"] = True
```

Comment: Exactly what I meant. Please check my edit for further open discussion! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the boolean operator `not`

```
>>> Gesture, Mouse, Keyboard = False, False, False 
>>> not Gesture
>>> True
>>> not Mouse
>>> True
>>> not Keyboard
>>> True
```

Comment: Thanks it helped. I edited my question with a working solution but still I don't trust the execution completely.

Answer (score 1):

Question is pretty unclear for me, hope I got it right.

An idea is simple, in each iteration I want to know previously enabled key to disable it easily. To enforce constant ordering of switching I built lists of keys (ordering in lists is preserved). So I built both lists and `zip`ed them. Sleep it there just for easier debug.

```
import time

state = {"gesture": False, "mouse": False, "keyboard": False}
keys = list(state.keys())  # list() is needed in Python3
previous_keys = keys[-1:]+keys[:-1]  # some slice syntax

def disable(key):
    global state
    print("Disabling", key)
    state[key] = False

def enable(key):
    global state
    print("Enabling", key)
    state[key] = True

while True:
    for active, previous in zip(keys, previous_keys):
        if state[previous]:
            disable(previous)
        enable(active)
        print("-")
        time.sleep(1)
```